# javascript: I am trying to delete the record from the table in service now

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to delete the record from external web page in Service Now. I have two file one is java script, and one is html. I have three field Name, grade, Purity Level. Here is my code, when I press the delete button instead of delete record, this code adding the record in my view page. I also attach the picture.

```
ondeleteReagant(){
    this.http.post('/api/now/table/x_197846_team_nan_reagent',"{'name':'"+this.name+"','grade':'"+this.grade+"','puritylevel':'"+this.puritylevel+"'}", this.httpOptions ).toPromise().then(resp=>{
      console.log(resp);
    },error=>{console.log(error)});
  }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: My delete function does not work

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: You have edited your question and removed the code, which will make it much harder for people to provide an answer.  Are you *sure* that code is JavaScript and not TypeScript?  Also, your delete command looks strange;  are you really trying to post the object to the server to initiate a delete?